# How to implement poll scm in GitHub actions?

Tags: github, jenkins, github-actions

In Jenkins, there is a poll scm option.

Which will run the job at a scheduled time only if there is any new change from previous build in source repository.

Is there any similar approach in GitHub actions.There is schedule option as in this [link](https://jasonet.co/posts/scheduled-actions/). But that won't check if any new changes there or not and trigger directly.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Actions doesn't implement a way to poll repositories, because generally polling is inefficient, especially at GitHub's scale.

Instead, you can specify the events you'd like to trigger your job.  For example, if you want to trigger a job anytime a push or pull request occurs, you'd use something like this:

```
on: [push, pull_request]
```

GitHub has [extensive documentation on what actions can trigger a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows).

It is true that you can schedule actions at a particular time, which can be useful if, say, your deployment system prunes old artifacts and you need to ensure that they're refreshed.  Generally, it's recommended that if you need to choose a periodic schedule, you do so with a random time to avoid thundering herd problems.